# reading and converting SQL QUERY to Azure Databricks/Spark python

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using azure databricks and I have the following sql query that I would like to convert into a spark python code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        personID,
        SUM(quantity) as total_shipped
FROM(
SELECT  p.personID,
        p.systemID,
        s.quantity
FROM shipped s
LEFT JOIN ordered p

on (s.OrderId = p.OrderNumber OR
substr(s.OrderId,1,6) = p.OrderNumber )

and p.ndcnum = s.ndc

where s.Dateshipped <= "2022-04-07"
AND personID is not null

group by personID
```

I intend to merge the spark dataframes first, then perform the aggregated sum. However, I think I am making it more complicated than it is. So far, this is what I have but I am getting `InvalidSyntax` error:

```
ordered.join(shipped, ((ordered("OrderId").or(ordered.select(substring(ordered.OrderId, 1, 6)))) === ordered("ORDERNUMBER")) &&
    (ordered("ndcnumber") === ordered("ndc")),"left")
      .show()
```

The part I am getting confused is on the OR statement from the SQL query, how do I convert that into a spark python statement?

Comment: Please share sample of your input data and its intended output. Also, explain your use case. Additionally, I'm just curious why can't you use simple sparkSql than creating equivalent in pyspark? Just use `df = spark.sql("Your Sql query")` to create your dataframe.

Comment: `===` and `&&` is scala

Comment: @DKNY thanks for reminding me. I forgot about that.

Comment: @pltc I am just learning and I have never used scala, I thought it is the same after googling. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is beauty in using databricks. you can directly use the same code by calling `spark.sql(""" {your sql query here} """)` and you will still get the same results. You can assign it to a variable and you will have a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks, Yes. I totally forgot about that. Thank you for confirming that I am making it more complicated than it should be.